# Custom JavaFX 8 objects

Tags: java, custom-controls, javafx-8, custom-component

I'm having trouble with javafx 8

I have a controller class that I've bound to a .fxml file.  This is the beginning of my constructor for the controller class.

```
public class SearchOverviewController {
    @FXML
    private TreeView<String> bookTree;
....
```

I tried to create a custom TreeView class called BookTree. This is to manage the TreeView and add children and whatnot.  I would like to separate that functionality into this class.

```
public class BookTree extends TreeView<String>{ 
    TreeItem rootItem;

    public BookTree() { 
        super();
        initRootItem();
        setupBookTree();
    }


    public void initRootItem(){
        rootItem = new TreeItem<String> ("Hello");
        this.setRoot(rootItem);
        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
    }

    private void setupBookTree(){       
        String[] items = {"hello", "how", "are", "you"};
        for(String s : items){
            addChildItem(rootItem, s);
        }
    }

    public void addChildItem(TreeItem localRootItem, String title){
        localRootItem.setExpanded(true);

        TreeItem<String> child = new TreeItem<String> (title);
        localRootItem.getChildren().add(child);
    }

    public void getChildItem(String name){
        //TODO implement
    }   
}
```

Then I modified my SearchOverviewController class to:

```
public class SearchOverviewController {
    @FXML
    private BookTree bookTree;
....
```

However when I try running it with these changes I get this error:

```
Could not load resource because of: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/Code/workspace/ocean2/target/classes/com/zurg/ocean2/view/SearchOverview.fxml:20
```

This is my SearchOverview.fxml for reference. The error is pointing to the line with: TreeView fx:id="bookTree" maxWidth="300.0"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<AnchorPane styleClass="background" stylesheets="@DarkTheme.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.zurg.ocean2.view.SearchOverviewController">
   <children>
      <HBox layoutX="15.0" layoutY="15.0" spacing="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="15.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="15.0">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="searchField" onAction="#searchButtonAction" HBox.hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#searchButtonAction" text="Search" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <Separator prefHeight="4.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="64.0" />
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="68.0">
        <items>
            <TreeView fx:id="bookTree" maxWidth="300.0">
               <effect>
                  <MotionBlur />
               </effect></TreeView>
            <TextArea fx:id="textArea" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I'm really confused as to why I can't create a custom JavaFX class.  I even attempted to make a manager class that would take the TreeView as a parameter and modify it similar to how my custom BookTree is set up currently to the same error message.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is the 1000th Javafx-8 question. I'd love to tell you that you win something, but...

Comment: haha. that's amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<TreeView ...>` instructs the `FXMLLoader` to instantiate a `TreeView`. The `fx:id` tries to assign it to the field declared as

```
private BookView bookTree ;
```

In plain Java, this would be similar to trying to call

```
private BookTree bookTree = new TreeView<?>();
```

which clearly would fail at complie time.

You should be able just to change your FXML to

```
<BookTree fx:id="bookTree" maxWidth="300.0"/>
```

Comment: Thanks!! You were almost completely right.

I also needed to add this line to imports:
<?import com.zurg.ocean2.view.BookTree?>